# Skyrim and draugr queries

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As draugr have a purpose: to defend their dragon priest masters, why are they mostly found defending a tomb with no dragon priest in it? Apart from a draugr overlord boss battle at the end depending on which tomb you go to. 
Did the overlords have the same power status over the draugr as the priests?

Comment: The only thing I can really find on Draugr being found guarding other treasures in barrows... pretty much just cites in-game evidence, that they *are* found doing this. In Norse Mythology (not to be confused with Elder Scrolls Lore, per se; I'm talking about real-life Norse Mythology), draugr live in their graves, guarding treasure buried with them. It makes sense to me that the Elder Scrolls means to reference this.

I believe the Draugr are supposed to be, more generally, reanimated Nord dead, and not *necessarily* followers of a Dragon Priest (though many are).

Answer (score 4):

According to Skyrim's wiki, not all Draugr were serving the dragons/priests. A lot of them are just plain undead warriors from Skyrim.

They seem to follow some kind of army hierarchy where there are a lot of regular soldiers (Draugr archers and swordsmen), some mages and a select number of overlords who probably commanded the troops when they were still alive.

Source: [Skyrim wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Draugr_%28Skyrim%29)